# Bit shift once to left upon an event

Tags: c

I am looking at a problem where I need to increment a counter. This counter works like an event memory holder of size 3. This means that you can store events that have been happening during the last three time slots.

E.g.:

- at time slot 0, there was a event: set mem_holder = 001
- at time slot 1, another event: shift mem_holder with 1 and and the new event -> 011
- at time slot 2, no event so we shift both bits with one to left -> 110
- at time slot 3, no event shift both again to left -> 100
- at time slot 4, new event -> 001
- at time slot 5, no event -> 010
- at time slot 6, new event -> 101

and so on and so forth

what I am looking for is a hint or an example of how to solve this in a proper and efficient way. 
The criteria is low complexity and low memory requirement i.e. no large variable allocation.

I know very little about bit operation, however I know the basics e.g. << | >> & ^ but combining them in a "large" context is challenging, so any advice / help is appreciated !

Thx in advanced

Comment: You already described how to do it, so I don't really understand what you want us to tell you

Comment: `&&` is not a *bit operation*

Comment: I was hoping for some implementation oriented advice e.g. how to carry the given example to practical code example

Comment: How about `(buffer << 1) | new_event` (this leaves more than 3 in the buffer but you can just ignore the extra)

Comment: Thank you Harold, this might just be the solution, simple to carry out. Yes, the buffer might get large but as you said, then this can be ignored. 
 Once again thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have a 3-bit integer, which means that it can hold values from b000 to b111, so 0 to 7. If you AND any integer with 7, you clear out anything but the rightmost 3 bits.

So, what you do, is you leftshift by one to make place for the new bit, then bitwise-and with 7. The newest rightmost bit is now 0 due to your leftshift. After this, if there's a new event, you set the rightmost bit to 1 using a bitwise-or.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mark(int new_event) {
    static int bits = 0;

    /* Shift the bits one left to make place for the new event bit.
     * Make sure only 3 bits are used. */
    bits <<= 1;
    bits &= 7;          /* 7 is in binary 111, all other bits get removed */

    /* Put in the rightmost bit a 1 if new_event is 'true', else it's
     * already zeroed-out due to the above leftshift */
    if (new_event)
        bits |= 1;
    /* Note: if you're sure that new_event can only have values 0 and 1, then
     * you can do an unconditional:
     *    bits |= new_event
     */

    /* Output what we've done for demo purposes */
    printf("New event: %d. Bits: ", new_event);
    putchar(bits & 4 ? '1' : '0');
    putchar(bits & 2 ? '1' : '0');
    putchar(bits & 1 ? '1' : '0');
    putchar('\n');
}

int main() {
    /* at time slot 0, there was a event: set mem_holder = 001
       at time slot 1, another event: shift mem_holder with 1
                       and and the new event -> 011
       at time slot 2, no event so we shift both bits with one to left -> 110
       at time slot 3, no event shift both again to left -> 100
       at time slot 4, new event -> 001
       at time slot 5, no event -> 010
       at time slot 6, new event -> 101
    */
    mark(1);
    mark(1);
    mark(0);
    mark(0);
    mark(1);
    mark(0);
    mark(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
New event: 1. Bits: 001
New event: 1. Bits: 011
New event: 0. Bits: 110
New event: 0. Bits: 100
New event: 1. Bits: 001
New event: 0. Bits: 010
New event: 1. Bits: 101
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can employ a not so complex logic:

```
mem_holder = (mem_holder*2)%8 + event
where event can take values [0,1].
```

Comment: Well, it's not really more complex than mem_holder = ((mem_holder << 1) & 7) | event, right?

Comment: All of the operations here are more complex than the bitwise equivalents and only equivalent because they're special cases that happen to be simple.